# Cross-platform library for generating pure sound with adjustable level of volume/dB written in C or C++

Tags: c, audio, cross-platform, audio-processing

I'm looking for a Cross-platform library for generating pure sound with adjustable level of power/dB written in C or C++. It must not be GPL.

Comment: How can a library know what the output volume level will be?  Doesn't that depend on external speaker settings, listener distance from speakers, etc?

Comment: thanks. I edited. Was writing in hurry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CLAM](http://clam-project.org/) is one such library that is GPL but the authors are willing to dual license (probably for a fee) if needed.

You dismiss the GPL, but not the LGPL - [LIBSDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) is another option if LGPL is acceptable for you.

Comment: +1 thank you Adam for quick reply. I'm looking into those. I want library to be able to run on embedded Linux/Linux phones as well.